# Mark days in calendarView with an array coming from firebase

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, calendarview

I'm getting a set of numbers from the firebase in an array, I want to now put the values ​​as days in CalendarView, I've already taken a look at the documentation, but I have not found anything to reproduce this.
Can someone help me?

### mounting array

```
datas = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new DatasAdapter(getActivity(), datas);
lastQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            datas.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Data data = dados.getValue(Data.class);

                datas.add(noticia);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

### Data Class

```
public class Data {
private int data;

public Data() {
}

public int getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(int data) {
    this.data = data;
 }
}
```

### How to fill CalendarView with this array?

[image]

Comment: You only said what you want to do, but didn't say why can't you do it. Is there an error?

Comment: Sorry for the badly worded question, my English is not the best. There is no mistake, I just want to know how to do this.